# Javascript selecting to save one index of split()

Tags: javascript, string, split, indexof

I have a value - `toggle-save_2`
I want to extract the `2` part. The part after the `underscore` will always be what i need but the length of the former part, which in this case is `toggle-save_`, may vary (eg. notoggle-val_45). Though this length may vary it will always be separated from the end number by an `underscore`.

Right now I am using this

```
var current = this.id.split('_');
current = current[1];
```

to select the number.

What would be cool is if I could pass a variable to the split to only give me the second index of the result from the split.

Comment: why not just this.id.split('_')[1]; Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select the 2nd index when you do the split.

```
var current = this.id.split('_')[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

The best solution here would be to use [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), like this

```
function getLastPart(strObject) {
    return strObject.substring(strObject.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
}

console.log(getLastPart("toggle-save_2"));
// 2
console.log(getLastPart("notoggle-save_45"));
// 45
```

It is better for this case because, you already know that the `_` will be somewhere near the last position. Since `lastIndexOf` starts from the last position, it would find `_` very soon and all we need to do is to get the rest of the string from the next position.

Comment: This is probably the most efficient way to do this and it's a very creative solution. I don't think it's as readable as Danny's answer -- if you don't know that substring() returns the rest of the string when you omit the length argument then it might not be immediately obvious what this code will do. Sometimes readability trumps efficiency, sometimes it doesn't. I think both answers are worth considering.

Comment: "_if you don't know_" Readability is subjective and at some point you just need to program. I mean, if you don't know JS, then JS isn't very readable--but we still need to program in it.

Answer (score 1):

There are often times I am breaking up a string where I only need the very last value of the result of `String.prototype.split` and consider the rest to be garbage no matter how many values the split produced.

When those cases arise, I like to chain [`Array.prototype.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) off of the `split`

```
var s = 'toggle-save_2',
    current = s.split('_').pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `split` method can only be limited from the end, and it will always return an array.

You don't need to use `split`, you can use string operations to get part of the string:

```
var current = this.id.substr(this.id.indexOf('_') + 1);
```